# Some rows can not be updated in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created an order management system website. There are multiple users. In the homepage users sees all the orders that they have entered.Admin sees all orders. There are two buttons which are update and delete.Only Admin can update and delete orders. The problem is, in most of the rows admin can update them but certain rows can not be updated. I could not figure out why. This is my updateotders php file :

```
<?php require_once 'header.php'; 
      require_once 'db/db.php'; 
    if(!$_SESSION['userId']) {
        header('location: http://yarkasiparis.xyz/index.php');    
    } 
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $_SESSION['rowid'] = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders where order_id = '".$_SESSION['rowid']."'";
        $result = $connect->query($sql) or die($connect->error);
        $connect->close();
    }
    $errors = array();
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
            $situation = $_POST["situation"];
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $surname = $_POST["surname"];
            $city = $_POST["city"];
            $district = $_POST["district"];
            $area = $_POST["area"];
            $address = $_POST["address"];
            $gsm1 = $_POST["gsm1"];
            $gsm2 = $_POST["gsm2"];
            $product = $_POST["product"];
            $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
            $price = $_POST["price"];
            $down_payment = $_POST["down_payment"];
            $explanation = $_POST["explanation"];
            //Form Validation
        if(empty($name) || empty($situation)) {
            if($name == "") {
                $errors[] = "İsim gerekli!";
            }
            if($situation == "") {
                $errors[] = "Durum gerekli!";
            }
        }else if(empty($surname) || empty($city)) {
            if($surname == "") {
                $errors[] = "Soyadı gerekli!";
            } 
            if($city == "") {
                $errors[] = "Şehir gerekli!";
            }
        }else if(empty($district) || empty($area)) {
            if($district == "") {
                $errors[] = "İlçe gerekli!";
            } 
            if($area == "") {
                $errors[] = "Bölge gerekli!";
            }
        }else if(empty($address) || empty($gsm1)) {
            if($address == "") {
                $errors[] = "Adres gerekli!";
            } 
            if($gsm1 == "") {
                $errors[] = "Gsm 1 gerekli!";
            }
        }else if(empty($product) || empty($quantity)) {
            if($product == "") {
                $errors[] = "Ürün gerekli!";
            } 
            if($quantity == "") {
                $errors[] = "Adet gerekli!";
            }
        }else if(empty($price) || empty($down_payment)) {
            if($price == "") {
                $errors[] = "Fiyat gerekli!";
            } 
            if($down_payment == "") {
                $errors[] = "Kapora gerekli!";
            }
        }else{                  
                $sql = "UPDATE orders SET order_situation = '$situation',
                             client_name = '$name', client_last_name ='$surname' , city ='$city' , district ='$district' 
                             , area ='$area' , address ='$address' , tel_no1 ='$gsm1' , tel_no2 ='$gsm2' , product ='$product' 
                             , quantity ='$quantity' , price ='$price' , down_payment ='$down_payment' , explanation ='$explanation' WHERE order_id='".$_SESSION['rowid']."'";
                $connect->query($sql) or die($connect->error);
                $connect->close();
            }
        header('Location: /homepage.php');
    }
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="messages">
        <?php if($errors) {
            foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i>
                '.$value.'</div>';                                      
                }
            } ?>
    </div>
    <h1 class="well">Sipariş Ver</h1>
    <div class="col-lg-12 well">
    <div class="row">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
                <?php  if (isset($result)) {while($userdata = $result->fetch_assoc()){?>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <p style= "margin-left: 15px; color: red">* olan alanlar zorunludur</p>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                             <label for="situation"> Durum Seçin: *</label>
                                  <select class="form-control" name = "situation">
                                    <option value="Beklemede" <?php if($userdata['order_situation'] == "Beklemede"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Beklemede </option>   
                                    <option value="Hazırlanıyor" <?php if($userdata['order_situation'] == "Hazırlanıyor"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Hazırlanıyor </option>
                                    <option value="Yolda" <?php if($userdata['order_situation'] == "Yolda"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Yolda </option>
                                    <option value="Tamamlandı" <?php if($userdata['order_situation'] == "Tamamlandı"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Tamamlandı </option>
                                    <option value="İptal Edildi" <?php if($userdata['order_situation'] == "İptal Edildi"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> İptal Edildi </option>
                                    <option value="Araç 1" <?php if($userdata['order_situation'] == "Araç 1"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Araç 1 </option>
                                    <option value="Araç 2" <?php if($userdata['order_situation'] == "Araç 2"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Araç 2 </option>
                                    <option value="Araç 3" <?php if($userdata['order_situation'] == "Araç 3"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Araç 3 </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                <label>Ad: *</label>
                                <input type="text" name = "name" value="<?php echo $userdata['client_name']; ?>" placeholder="Adınızı buraya girin..." class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                <label>Soyad: *</label>
                                <input type="text" name = "surname" value="<?php echo $userdata['client_last_name']; ?>" placeholder="Soyadınızı buraya girin.." class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                <label>İl: *</label>
                                <input type="text" name = "city" value="<?php echo $userdata['city']; ?>" placeholder="İli buraya girin.." class="form-control">
                            </div>  
                            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                <label>İlçe: *</label>
                                <input type="text" name = "district" value="<?php echo $userdata['district']; ?>" placeholder="İlçeyi buraya girin.." class="form-control">
                            </div>      
                            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                <label for="area"> Bölge Seçin: *</label>
                                  <select class="form-control" name = "area">
                                    <option value="Karadeniz" <?php if($userdata['area'] == "Karadeniz"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Karadeniz </option>   
                                    <option value="Marmara" <?php if($userdata['area'] == "Marmara"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Marmara </option>
                                    <option value="İç Anadolu" <?php if($userdata['area'] == "İç Anadolu"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> İç Anadolu </option>
                                    <option value="Doğu Anadolu" <?php if($userdata['area'] == "Doğu Anadolu"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Doğu Anadolu </option>
                                    <option value="Güneydoğu Anadolu" <?php if($userdata['area'] == "Güneydoğu Anadolu"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Güneydoğu Anadolu </option>
                                    <option value="Ege" <?php if($userdata['area'] == "Ege"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Ege </option>
                                  </select>
                            </div>      
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Adres: *</label>
                            <textarea name = "address" placeholder="Adresinizi buraya girin..." rows="3" class="form-control"><?php echo $userdata['address']; ?></textarea>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label>GSM no 1: *</label>
                                <input type="text" name = "gsm1" value="<?php echo $userdata['tel_no1']; ?>" placeholder="Birinci tel numarası..." class="form-control">
                            </div>      
                            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label>GSM no 2:</label>
                                <input type="text" name = "gsm2" value="<?php echo $userdata['tel_no2']; ?>" placeholder="İkinci tel numarası..." class="form-control">
                            </div>  
                        </div>                      
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label for="product">Ürün Seçin: *</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name = "product">
                                        <option value="Ataks" <?php if($userdata['product'] == "Ataks"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Ataks </option>   
                                        <option value="Lohman" <?php if($userdata['product'] == "Lohman"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Lohman </option>
                                        <option value="İsa Dekalp" <?php if($userdata['product'] == "İsa Dekalp"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> İsa Dekalp </option>
                                        <option value="Horoz" <?php if($userdata['product'] == "Horoz"){  ?> selected <?php  }  ?>> Horoz </option>
                                    </select>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label>Adet: *</label>
                                <input type="text" name = "quantity" value="<?php echo $userdata['quantity']; ?>" placeholder="Adeti buraya girin.." class="form-control">
                            </div>          
                        </div>  
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label>Fiyat: *</label>
                                <input type="text" name = "price" value="<?php echo $userdata['price']; ?>" placeholder="Fiyatı buraya girin.." class="form-control">
                            </div>  
                            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label>Kapora: *</label>
                                <input type="text" name = "down_payment" value="<?php echo $userdata['down_payment']; ?>" placeholder="Kaporayı buraya girin.." class="form-control">
                            </div>          
                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Açıklama:</label>
                            <textarea name = "explanation" value="<?php echo $userdata['explanation']; ?>" placeholder="Açıklamayı buraya girin..." rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" name = "update" value = "Güncelle" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">
                    </div>
                <?php }}?>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
            window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
        }
    </script>
<?php require_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

These are the sample rows that can not be updated:

(`order_id`, `order_situation`, `client_name`, `client_last_name`, `city`, `district`, `area`, `address`, `tel_no1`, `tel_no2`, `product`, `quantity`, `price`, `down_payment`, `explanation`, `user_id`, `username`, `date`) VALUES (149, 'Beklemede', 'SÜLEYMAN', 'BEY', 'ISPARTA', 'MERKEZ', 'Akdeniz', 'DERE MAHALESİ', '5357342247', '', 'Lohman', 200, 15.5, 0, '09.10.2017 AŞI KARNESİ', 34, 'sezer', '2017-11-10 08:51:10');

(`order_id`, `order_situation`, `client_name`, `client_last_name`, `city`, `district`, `area`, `address`, `tel_no1`, `tel_no2`, `product`, `quantity`, `price`, `down_payment`, `explanation`, `user_id`, `username`, `date`) VALUES (87, 'Beklemede', 'UFUK', 'DEDE', 'HATAY', 'DEFNE', 'Güneydoğu Anadolu', 'AKNEHİR MH', '5368893695', '', 'Lohman', 100, 16, 0, 'FİYAT SORULACAK', 34, 'sezer', '2017-11-08 14:54:07');

Maybe this is about database:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_situation` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `district` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(350) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `tel_no1` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET armscii8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `tel_no2` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET armscii8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `down_payment` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `explanation` varchar(350) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci;
```

I know most of the parts are turkish if anyone can help I would be grateful.

I am not an experienced programmer so if I have mistakes forgive me.

Comment: *"These are the sample rows that can not be updated"*- So why are you using INSERT?

Comment: I am sorry I just wanted show the rows this is not about this. I will edit it.

Comment: check for errors then

Comment: It does not give me errors. I think that this is about table structure but I could not figure out.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of the issue. Also use parameterized queries, in addition to SQL injections any single quote will break your query. Also when making your mysqli connection did you set the encoding?

Comment: Your code is pure mess. There are so many if else statements that is going to make it hard for you to debug the code and even harder for us to review. I would suggest to print the final sql before the update for the rows you cannot update and see if the row id is missing. Maybe even run the query manually to check if it works

Comment: Have you tried your queries outside PHP?  Print them in PHP and try them directly on the database.  This might point out to some issue in the query.

Comment: One thing to try is to stop closing the connection after the first select.  This could mean you've already closed your database connection before you try and do any update

Comment: I tried echo out the id in those that are not updating nothing shows but the others are showing. When I click on url it shows the id but it does't get the value. Any ideas why?

Comment: I found the problem when I commented the if statements above and echo out the id it gave me the id. Anyways thank you for your responses.